# Cron doesn't execute one of the scheduled jobs

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, log, touchscreen

I'm using a lubuntu desktop, distribution Ubuntu 13.10, i686. This is my problem:
in the job list scheduled by cron a job hasn't effect, but in /var/log/syslog its execution is traced. This is the relative log line:

**Jun 4 09:06:01 kiosk CRON[14189]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/xinput set-prop 12 --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 >> /tmp/mybackup.log)**

This job should rotate touchscreen mapping.

I try different solutions: I substitute in crontab the  with bash -c "", I set "export DISPLAY=:0.0" ("for Graphics related job in Unix Environment we need to set first the DISPLAY...") before the command,...and many other!

I know there are a lots of details affect cron execution (path, environment variables, special character and other) and I have no more idea by now :(

Could some gentleman suggest me an idea? where can I find the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`xinput` configures and tests X input devices. It uses the `$DISPLAY` environment variable to find the X server to talk to, so you need to define it, because cron jobs do not require X windows. The easy way is to have the crontab line be

```
env DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/xinput set-prop 12 --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 >> /tmp/mybackup.log
```

Is there an X server running when the cronjob runs? Also, if there is an X server running, it might be running with the X authentication credentials of a user, and your cron log shows you running as `root`. If you are not exposed, and are willing to risk reducing your X security, try running

```
xhost +SI:localhost:root
```

on your X server at each login. Or, run the cron job as the same user, not `root`.

Comment: I tried your advice but I have the same behavior. I confirm that I have an x server running

Comment: Compare the `cron` environment with the working environment, thusly:  

`$ env | sort >x.environment`  

`$ crontab -l`  

`# m h  dom mon dow   command`  

`*   *  *   *   *     env | sort >cron.environment`  

$ sleep 60  

$ ls -l {cron,x}.environment  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt  112 Jun  8 19:40 cron.environment  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt 4216 Jun  8 19:38 x.environment  
$ diff {cron,x}.environment  
.......<snip, YMMV>.......`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting - command lines start with "$"

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I could not format the comment the way I liked.

Compare the `cron` environment with the working environment, thusly:

```
$ env | sort >x.environment  
$ crontab -l  
# m h  dom mon dow   command  
*   *  *   *   *     env | sort >cron.environment  
$ sleep 60  
$ ls -l {cron,x}.environment  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt  112 Jun  8 19:40 cron.environment  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt 4216 Jun  8 19:38 x.environment  
$ diff {cron,x}.environment  
.......<snip, YMMV>.......
```